# Widget CSS being interfered with by external page CSS

Tags: javascript, css, widget

Just created a javascript widget that injects the content on the 3rd party site using DOM. I include a css file with the widget. However, I keep running into instances where the external pages css will interfere with the widget css and add something weird like a background image or border too my widget elements that I don't have defined in my css. Any easy way to go around this? I've already added

```
!important
```

to all the css rules. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have an example we can look at?

Comment: could you give an example of css being injected? how is it injected and where?

Answer (score 1):

As in my opinion, I, with no doubt, say that in the external css, not the widget css, have added something that would add the border or background to ALL divs. You might want to check that out.